# Does linux -x86 having device tree (where)?

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I am working on "ALSA" audio driver and I am trying to find out flow of driver for that I need to see device tree file in X86 arc but I am not able to see.

Comment: There are only few platforms that support DT on x86: OLPC (1st version), Intel Sodaville (D-Link TV box, and other TVs from that time, ~2011), and SpreadTrum (the most recent device is a phone from ~2018). I think you are more interested in ACPI.

Comment: For supporting hardware plugged in to a dev board with fixed ACPI tables, you may be interested in using [SSDT Overlays](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/acpi/ssdt-overlays.html) to dynamically load extensions to the built-in tables.